# log and write with php?

Tags: php, logging, text-files

well i have this php to log and write my text from a textarea but its only logging. Help?

```
<?php 
$fn = "test.txt"; //the path to any file

if (isset($_POST['content'])) 
{ 
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']); 
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!"); 
    fputs($fp,$content); 
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!"); 
} 
?> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "Stickies.css";
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="practiceDiv"></div>
<div id="front">
    <img src='Images/yellow.png' id='frontImg'/>    
    <img src="Images/notAllowed.png" id="dont"/>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <textarea name="txt" style="font-family: Marker Felt; font-size: 16px; background-color: transparent; border: none; height:159px; resize: none;" id="myDiv" onkeydown="handleTyping(event);" onkeyup="handleKeyUp(event);" onpaste="handlePaste(event);" name="content"><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"> 
<?php
$x = $_POST['txt'];
?> 
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?
$string = $x
?>
<?

$filename = 'log.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, "a+");
$write = fputs($fp, $string . "\r\n");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: you already called the textarea name txt, then you call it content later along the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed your example, hope it helps

```
<?php 
$fn = "test.txt"; //the path to any file

//get posted content from the textarea
if (isset($_POST['txt'])) 
{ 
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['txt']); 
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w+") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!"); 
    fputs($fp,$content); 
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!"); 
} 
?> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "Stickies.css";
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="practiceDiv"></div>
<div id="front">
    <img src='Images/yellow.png' id='frontImg'/>    
    <img src="Images/notAllowed.png" id="dont"/>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <!-- removed the name="content"-->
    <textarea name="txt" style="font-family: Marker Felt; font-size: 16px; background-color: transparent; border: none; height:159px; resize: none;" id="myDiv" onkeydown="handleTyping(event);" onkeyup="handleKeyUp(event);" onpaste="handlePaste(event);" ><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"> 

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!--your php short tag may not be supported-->
<?php
$filename = 'log.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, "a");
//used $content var instead of making new one
fputs($fp, $content . "\r\n");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: glad to help, it was most probably the short tags.

Comment: since its a text area, every time it logs i get more and more spaces in-between posts

Answer (score 0):

people usually prefer `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` over `fputs & fgets`,

it saves us some lines of code, and more simplicity.